# What Windows 10 driver model is appropriate for implementing IP link layer?

Tags: windows, serial-port, driver

I'm looking to write a simple Windows driver to enable running TCP/IP over a proprietary RF module. The module already provides Ethernet-style data packets with source/destination MAC, so I just need to layer IP packets (generated by the regular Microsoft IPv4 subsystem), set the MTU appropriately so they will be the right size, and then call the module's serial API. I'll need to be able to handle transmit statuses and implement an ARP protocol as well. I want the driver to expose a new interface similar to a wifi or ethernet card in Network Connections and use the normal Windows IP stack.

The module is UART and might be connected via FTDI chip, RS-232 converter, or native UART on an IoT Core board, so it will just be talking to a generic serial port. I am fine with only running on Windows 10, but I'm still not sure what to use. Can I use the UWP VPN provider? Do I need to write an NDIS miniport driver, or an interface provider? Also, how will I handle the driver needing complete control over the serial port at all times? I can't write a serial driver as it might be connected via many different types of serial ports.